# Is it possible to make Typescript aware of the dependency versions defined in the package.json?

Tags: typescript, npm, yarn-workspaces

I have realised that when I run tsc on a project with a certain dependency the compilation will succeed as long as any version of the dependency is present in my system anywhere in the Node's module resolution path.

For instance:

- In a monorepo managed with yarn workspaces that contains two packages (**project_1** and **project_2**)
- If **project_1** has declared a dependency **dep_1** in its package.json
- After running yarn install so **dep_1** is added to the root node_modules

I can now use import statements for **dep_1** in **project_2** without adding **dep_1** to the **project_2**'s package.json and tsc will not complain at compilation time.

Can this behaviour be changed to make Typescript aware of the dependencies declared in each project's package.json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an inherent issue of hoisting packages and the reason many packages around are botched. Nevertheless, TSLint provides the [`no-implicit-dependencies`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-implicit-dependencies/) rule to prevent importing hoisted packages not listed as direct dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. I've also found this document in lerna that explains it: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/master/doc/hoist.md

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not specific to TypeScript. You would be able to do the same from plain JavaScript. It is inherent to hoisting.